# How to kill opened files that does not reside in a directory entered by user?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Sometimes I open files from different source trees to compare with current tree.
I would like to have a function that kills all these opened files that does not reside in a "default tree" that the user is prompt to keep or change at the time the function is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Set default-tree to the name of the directory you want (it must be an absolute path).

```
(defun bruce-connor-buffer-killer ()
(interactive)
(unless (file-directory-p default-tree) (error "You forgot to set `default-tree'."))
(let ((case-fold-search nil)
      (dir-length (length default-tree)))
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (when (buffer-file-name buffer)
    (unless (equal t (compare-strings
                      (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name buffer)) 0 dir-length
                      default-tree 0 nil)))
       (kill-buffer buffer)))))
```

Comment: Hi Bruce,
Thanks for your answer...I did the following:

(defun kill-other-files
  (let ((case-fold-search nil)
      (dir-length (length default-tree)))
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (if (null (equal t (compare-strings (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name buffer)) 0 (- dir-length 1) 
                      default-tree 0 nil)))
       (kill-buffer buffer))))
)
(global-set-key [f6]          'kill-other-files)


But I get this message:
Wrong type argument: commandp, kill-other-files

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My bad, forgot to make the function interactive. Silly mistake

Comment: if: Symbol's function definition is void: directory-p

Comment: I had the wrong function name, try again. (It's hard to do this from my phone, but we'll get there) =)

Comment: @Ammari I now realise the documentation for compare-strings was not as trustworthy as I hoped, so I replaced the `(- dir-length 1)` part with `dir-length`. Let me know how everything works.